# Move elements of vectors c++

Tags: c++, vector

How can I move **certain elements** of a vector into another vector while making the original smaller? I don't want to make a copy, i want to for example: in a vector of 5 elements, move the 1st element to another vector and now the original will have 4 elements.

Comment: Vector's aren't usually used for that.

Comment: You can't do that in one operation. It wouldn't be useful anyway, since vector is not a node-based container and there isn't actually any physical "thing" that you could move.

Answer (score 2):

First you want to use push_back to add the item to the second vector, then use erase to remove the item from the first vector. Both of these are members of the std::vector class.

An example:

```
std::vector<int> vec1, vec2;
//populate the first vector with some stuff
vec1.push_back(1);
vec1.push_back(2);
vec1.push_back(3); // so the vecotr is now { 1, 2, 3}
//Then move item 2 to the second vector
vec2.push_back(vec1[2]);
vec1.erase(2);
```

Edit:
Though as others have pointed out, it looks like a vector may not be what you are looking for if this isn't the functionality you want. Have a look at the [STL containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) to see if there is something that is more fit for purpose.

Comment: If this is what he wants to do and if "this" refers to your code, then vectors are completely fine. However, if he was looking for moving things around rather than pushing things around, then vectors dont offer what he is looking for

Comment: @tobi303 sorry that should have been "isn't" thanks for catching it

Comment: Shouldn't that be `vec1.erase(2)`?  The item at `vec(2)` doesn't exist, since only one item is in `vec2`.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<std::string> v1 = {"hello", "hello", "world", "c++", "hello", "stuff"};
std::vector<std::string> v2;

auto const pos = std::stable_partition(
    v1.begin(), v1.end(),
    [](std::string const& i) {
        // Condition in here. Return false to "remove" it.
         return "hello" != i;
    });
std::move(pos, v1.end(), std::back_inserter(v2));
// If you don't want to maintain current contents of v2, then
// this will be better than std::move:
// v2.assign(std::make_move_iterator(pos),
//           std::make_move_iterator(v1.end()));
v1.erase(pos, v1.end());
```

If you wanted to, you could write your own helper function to encapsulate this. [See it working here](http://ideone.com/5sCWCq).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::move` to get a movable reference.

Not all types will allow you to move them. Also it's not guranteed that the instance you moved is in a correct state.

After you move you need to erase the location from the vector which will cause all the elements until the end of the vector to be copied/moved into the right position.

Comment: There's a double use, too. `std::move` is an algorithm to move a range.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not care about ordering you may use this:

```
std::swap(v1[index_of_item],v1.back());
v2.push_back(std::move(v1.back()));
v1.pop_back();
```